# Windows Azure Compute Emulator Crash

Tags: azure

We have an application using Windows Azure. Currently running SDK version 2.2.

When starting the Azure Compute Emulator role it crashes with the following error :

```
DiagnosticsAgent.exe - Application Error

The exception unknown software exception (0xe0434352) occurred in
the application at location 0xfd58940d.
```

The following information is in the Application Event Log :

```
Fault bucket 3942935619, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: diagnosticsagent.exe
P2: 2.2.6492.1
P3: 5243ef34
P4: msshrtmi
P5: 2.2.1198.9
P6: 5230da64
P7: 238
P8: 33
P9: RML5K4UDBMA5NI04CIYRWVDHKEWFDHCV
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\carlwright\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA05F.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\carlwright\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_diagnosticsagent_33ba60237df0947a4b821be7cbe18d27c8f688a_1186b160

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: a8f0919b-bb30-11e3-adf5-534e57000000
Report Status: 0

Faulting application name: DiagnosticsAgent.exe, version: 2.2.6492.1, time stamp: 0x5243ef34
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1677
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000940d
Faulting process id: 0x718
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf4f3d6d96ffaf
Faulting application path: c:\Source\YogaClicks\Trunk\WindowsAzureYoga\csx\Debug\roles\Clicks.Yoga.Portal.ImageStore\plugins\Diagnostics\DiagnosticsAgent.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: ab53c655-bb30-11e3-adf5-534e57000000
```

Answer (score -2):

May be worth trying Azure SDK 2.3 (the version released yesterday) to see if this still reproduces.
Also check out this blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/09/12/general-steps-to-investigate-problems-with-windows-azure-diagnostics.aspx

And consider setting UseDevelopmentStorage=false on your project's settings.
There's a thread on this that may be helpful - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/09/12/general-steps-to-investigate-problems-with-windows-azure-diagnostics.aspx

Comment: I have just this minute upgraded to Azure 2.3 and the problem still persists.